# Reading value of first dropdown from Extended Choice Parameter - Multi-Level single select

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, 
Using **Extended Choice Parameter** plugin, I am creating a Multi-Level single select
[image]

the "Name" of the parameter gives value of the second dropdown.. 
that is ${SITE_SELECTION} contains Message1

How could i get the value of the first dropdown?

Comment: Good observation, I wasn't able to find it either

Comment: 1. If second dropdown has a value selected, that value will be returned.
2. But if the second dropdown doesn't have a value, the value of the first is returned.
Probably need to report a bug(maybe enhancement) for the  **Extended Choice Parameter**